# Google Auth sign in - Redirect URI Mismatch

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I am trying to add Google OAuth login/register to my app, first testing it locally then on the web.

Google OAuth has been set up. Redirect URLs as below:
[image]

A 'sign in' button on the login page loads the login route.

The code in the **routes.py** file is:

```
# Create a LoginManager and Flask-OAuthlib object

login_manager = LoginManager()
oauth = OAuth()


# Configure Flask-OAuthlib to use the Google OAuth API

google = oauth.remote_app(
    'google',
    consumer_key='377916639662-b3hlrf0tqbr4ib13bg8jgu1dsltfin8s.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    consumer_secret='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',
    request_token_params={
        'scope': 'email'
    },
    base_url='https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/',
    request_token_url=None,
    access_token_method='POST',
    access_token_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
    authorize_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
)


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(google_id):
    return User.query.get(google_id)


# Login

@accounts_bp.route('/login')
def login():
    return render_template('login.html')


@accounts_bp.route('/google-login')
def google_login():
    callback = url_for(
        'accounts_bp.authorized',
        _external=True,
        next=request.args.get('next') or request.referrer or None
    )
    return google.authorize(callback=callback)


@accounts_bp.route('/authorized')
def authorized():
    resp = google.authorized_response()
    if resp is None:
        return 'Access denied: reason=%s error=%s' % (
            request.args['error_reason'],
            request.args['error_description']
        )
    session['google_token'] = (resp['access_token'], '')
    me = google.get('userinfo')
    user = User.query.filter_by(google_id=me.data['id']).first()
    if not user:
        user = User(google_id=me.data['id'], name=me.data['name'], email=me.data['email'])
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
    login_user(user)
    return redirect(url_for('dashboard_bp.app_home'))
```

The error during Google sign in is "Request Invalid: redirect_uri_mismatch":
[image]

**Question:** What is causing the redirect uri mismatch and how to resolve it?

Comment: Do they match the 'Authorised JavaScript origins' row-for-row...?
e.g. http://localhost:81/login

Comment: likely the issue is `http` versus `https`. The callback URI needs to match _exactly_

Comment: @StevenDiffey why would I use Authorised js origins when my request comes from a web server not browser? Happy to find out that is the problem if so. Also, nothing is on https at the moment, you can see the image I posted from the console vs the code, all http.

Comment: we cannot see the actual webpage that it's coming from tho. Are you sure you're not on https?

Comment: Yes I'm running on my local machine, so no https.

Answer (score 0):

Setup Https on your local machine, following these instructions:
https://link.medium.com/ZEhdGL9T6wb

Then add the origin and redirect to Google Credentials, ensuring they match and do not have trailing slashes, etc.

I integrated Google's code generator recently. It's nicely simple.
https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/tools/configurator